# Atomic and Concurrent Safe Redis Transactions in Golang

Tags: go, concurrency, redis, transactions

I'm trying to implement the following logic in my go program:

```
def action:
 1. GET the value of KEY from Redis
 2. SET the value of KEY to 0
```

I'm using [`go-redis`](http://%22github.com/go-redis/redis%22) module to interact with my Redis instance.

I'm familiar with Redis transactions but I couldn't seem to find a decent document or example on how to implement the desired set of actions in a concurrent-safe and atomic manner in Golang.

**Question**: How can I implement the defined `action` and be sure no other Redis operation will take place between steps 1 and 2 even if I access my Redis instance from different go routines?

Comment: Use the [transaction](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#example-Client-TxPipeline) feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using the single Redis command [`GETSET`](https://redis.io/commands/getset), which will be atomic:

```
GETSET KEY 0
```

More broadly, there's nothing Go-specific about ensuring atomicity in Redis. You just use the same Redis transaction facilities (via the Go Redis client) that you're familiar with.

Comment: thanks but what if I needed to implement a different set of actions which don't have an atomic equivalent command?